# Linking mutiple 3rd party and Local accounts together with Passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, authorization, passport.js

I've succeeded in linking `Accounts` to `Users` as suggested [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/). If a logged-in user authorizes a 3rd party with OAuth 2.0 (eg. Google Contacts API), I am able to save that information in an Account and then tie that account to the logged-in User.

I'd like to take this a step further to make as seamless of a login experience as possible. Once a user has tied their identity to a 3rd party account, I'd like for them not only to be able to login using the Local Strategy(username/pwd) to then pull in relevant 3rd party information, but the other way as well: when logged out, connecting to Google will log them in as a user of my app, making req.user = their `User` info just as it is when they login using the Local strategy. Here is the relevant chunk of code (there is much more to is that shown, but the point is there.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: google_params.client_id,
        clientSecret: google_params.client_secret,
        callbackURL: google_params.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

...
        // If no user in session, set the req.user to the associated user
        User.findOne({
        'username': account.userId
        }, function(err, user) {
            console.log('Account exists already in DB, and is already tied to a user. Logging into users account.');
            req.user = user;
            return done(null, account);
        });

etc...
```

Upon checking the serialize/deserialize functions, this code never serializes the user or the account information to the session, so while that information does get passed along at the end of the verify callback, it disappears on a page refresh (again, because nothing is getting saved to the session). What do I do? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit late with an answer but I've been looking into this for an app I'm building and it may help someone else.

So the answer is that yes you can let a user link their accounts without requiring them to create a Local account (as suggested in the Scotch.io tutorial). The trick is managing the deduplication of the accounts.

No matter what provider they log in with we handle the following checks in order :

1. If a user already exists for this provider : log them back in.
2. If no user exists already for this provider : check to see if a users exists for the email address (or other common field across providers). If so link the accounts and log them in.
3. If there is no user already for this or another provider: create a new user model with information pulled from the provider and then log them in.

This should be done for all providers that you support. By using common fields that would be prevalidated by a third party service (such as email address) then we can de-duplicate accounts. Another feature may be to allow a user to link them together manually for cases where they want to link accounts that have different email addresses (this happens a lot with github where they use their personal account and then want to hook it up to a work account, for CI provider for example)

Hope this helps. If you came to an alternate solution it would be good to add it here or if you ran into any issues. I think this is a common enough case that it could be turned into a wiki.

**** UPDATES ****

- **Comment from @jaredhanson**

  After going through a lot of possible flows and a lot of googling, [I found this gist with a great comment from @jaredhanson (the author of passport.js) describing this exact scenario.](https://gist.github.com/joshbirk/1732068)

  I've reproduced the comment below (in case the gist disappears in the future)

> If you want to "link" accounts from multiple providers together, at
>   that point you'll want a database with user records specific to your
>   app, which in turn are associated with third-party account records.
>   Then, in the verify callback, you'll want to perform whatever queries
>   are necessary and supply your app-specific user record to done. That
>   will keep things consistent, so that if someone had linked both
>   Facebook and Twitter, they can return to the app and sign in with
>   either one.
>
> Further discussion about that topic is here:
>   http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize.html
>
> If you go that route (as I do in my apps), I use middleware like this
>   to combine authentication and authorization into a single route:
>
> ```
> function authnOrAuthzFacebook(req, res, next) {
>   if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
>     passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/settings/accounts',
>                                         failureRedirect: '/login' })(req, res, next);
>   } else {
>     passport.authorize('facebook-authz')(req, res, next);
>   }
> }
>
> app.get('/facebook-login', authnOrAuthzFacebook);
> ```

The application example that this comment was on [can be seen here on GitHub](https://github.com/joshbirk/socialnode) (in its final version).

- **stackoverflow Questions**

  Following on from this there is another stackoverflow question that also helps if you need to force a user to log in to different providers (think of how zapier needs access to multiple accounts for integration but not for auth). [Using passport.js with multiple strategies without overwriting user request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453527/using-passport-js-with-multiple-strategies-without-overwriting-user-request-obje/30224234#30224234)

So there are a few alternative version that will do the same job (depending on how you want to handle it).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together